# Informatica data update. Must have Id mapped

Tags: api, informatica

So we pull data from SAP quotes/sales and push it into a custom object in SFDC.

How we reference the records in SFDC to the ones in SAP is via the SAP sales doc #. In fact when you view this is Informatica you can see in both SAP and SFDC the Sales doc. and SAP_Sales_Doc__c and keys.

Now theres another field ORCL in SAP it's a boolen value true/false (or X/blank) and i need to push that to the related records in SFDC. The problem is when i try to us data synchronization it tells me "The ID field in salesforce.com object must be mapped for update." How the hell am i supposed to map to this field when there's nothing in SAP that references that.....the only reference to records i have is via the SAP sales doc.

i should mention the SAP_Sales_Doc__c field is an external ID

Answer (score 0):

Without a Salesforce ID, you need to use the upsert function. The instructions for doing so are in the [Informatica KB 124909](https://kb.informatica.com/howto/3/Pages/124909.aspx). It has a lot of pictures, so I can't really copy-paste the details, but you need to map the SAP Sales Doc # to the `SAP_Sales_Doc__c`, configure insert and updates as upserts, and specify `SAP_Sales_Doc__c` as the external ID for upsert operations.